# Why does JavaScript need the ECMAScript standard?

Tags: javascript

Why would you have a language and a specification/standard for that language? Isn't it just another layer of complexity?

C#, C++ - they don't have standards. Then why does JavaScript need a standard and C# doesn't?

Comment: C++ definitely does have a standard. I'd hazard a guess that C# does as well. You need to have it spelled out how a language should behave or you end up with a Brainfuck situation where certain code requires certain implementations to behave properly.

Comment: [The C++ stabndard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) is probably [the most well known, discussed, and dissected standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer%20c%2b%2b) out there. [C# also has specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction). [As does Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). I'm not quite sure why you believe JavaScript is any exception here.

Comment: Without a standard, you wouldn't have a language - or how else would the language be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You may not need a house plan for a small wooden hut, but you better have a plan for a three stories house.
When you draw the plan, you can identify errors and change course, preventing costy mistakes.

So, a language specification is necessary beyond certain complexity.
A language specification is also more than the spec itself; the specification process is equally important in a language's development.

---

Yeah, most programming languages *do* have/had a standard.
[C#](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm), [C++](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), even [PowerShell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=36389).
Both Perl and PHP had gone without spec for an extended period of time, when they were limited to a single implementation.
(Yes, a language *can* success without a spec.)
PHP got a spec for [maintaining HipHop](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/08/01/php_draft_specification/), an alternative engine.
Perl 6 got [two compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Perl_6) after the spec.

In case of the JavaScript of Netscape Navigator, IE [copied it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Adoption_by_Microsoft) as JScript, and Flash copied it as ActionScript.
Netscape, as the major browser at the time, responsibly submitted it to ECMA to ensure compatibility.
First version is out on 1997.

Yes, ECMAScript wasn't born at version 5.
It was born in 20th century.

The spec successfully kept the rapidly evolving core language cross-platform.
For example, ver 3 added regular expression and try catch, and all browsers implements them the same way ([more or less](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug)), thanks to the spec.

But ver 4 was a failure.  The vendors had [differed ideas](https://auth0.com/blog/the-real-story-behind-es4/), with ECMAScript [splitting into two](https://johnresig.com/blog/ecmascript-harmony/) and Microsoft, who won the first browser war, lost interest and went its own way (JScript.Net).
The in-fighting would last 10 years, during which the core JavaScript is effectively frozen.

And so the [second browser war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_wars#Second_Browser_War_(2004%E2%80%932017)) started *without a new JS spec*.
[Many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) [frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS) [arose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools) [to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUI_Library#Features) [extend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backbone.js) [JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit#Widgets), commonly adding methods to native objects and implementing their own class engine, mutually incompatible with each other.

The browser vendors realised that they *need* to end the fight.

Thus born ES5.  It [brings](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch25.html) many much needed methods (Array.find .map .forEach etc.), JSON, getter and setter, and a strict mode which lay the foundation for ES6.
It is a real breakthrough as it [unified](https://johnresig.com/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/) all major browsers to a common standard.

ES5 started a new JS age.

Soon after ES5, we get many language features that we now take for granted: class, for of, Map, Set, TypedArray, Promise, await async, arrow function, etc.
The vendors [discuss](https://esdiscuss.org/) *every single feature* thoroughly, experiment with them, to make sure each new feature will fit seamlessly, will run fast, and does not break the web.

For example, `Array.contains` was proposed for ES6.
After the draft, it was [found](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible) that a common libraries (by then) adds its own Array.contains and is incompatible.
In the end, the final spec is changed to `Array.includes`, ensuring sites that use the library won't break.

ES6's `let` and `const` also [differs](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/10/14/breaking-changes-let-const-firefox-nightly-44/) from the failed ES4.
The ES6 version is more useful, more precise, and backward compatibility was possible to maintain thanks to strict mode.

(Yes.  [Backward compatibility](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/about/faq/#breaking).
Ever heard of the [`with` statement](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077317/understanding-and-using-javascript-statements.html?page=2#with)?  It is still [in the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-with-statement).
For such a simple shorthand, it causes many [headaches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Description) and is thus [deprecated](https://2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html).
Similarly for [`caller`](https://medium.com/@bmeurer/function-caller-considered-harmful-45f06916c907).
Part of JavaScript's high complexity lies in its chaotic history.)

There are too many "backstage" talks like these to list, that will be difficult to discuss in advance without a specification process.
Whether you are aware of them or not, we all reap the benefits.

---

Thanks to spec, all browser's JavaScript and core objects overwhelmingly behaves the same.

Thanks to spec, those that do not are easy to identify, and fix is prioritised.

Thanks to spec, backward and forward compatibility can be better discussed and preserved.

Thanks to spec, the increasingly complex language core is still consistent and fast.

Thanks to spec, JavaScript can evolve as a unified entity, despite the independent browsers fighting each other for market share.

Language specification is complex, yes, but it is necessary for the health of the language.
Kind of like JavaScript [class](https://dev.to/smalluban/do-we-really-need-classes-in-javascript-after-all-91n).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I only have one more question. So, the result of the Javascript code is dependent on how a certain browser decides to realize it?

Comment: @PetroKoval Kind of. The spec is pretty solid, but some areas are undefined such as native objects. For example, what happens when you `Object.create( document.all )` is undefined and depends on the browser.  Also, [no browsers](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) implement the spec 100%.  But generally speaking, for every day code you may consider the browsers compatible with each other.